# Elegant Json flatten in Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe in spark:

```
val test = sqlContext.read.json(path = "/path/to/jsonfiles/*")  
test.printSchema
root
 |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- prop_1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- prop_2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- prop_3: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- prop_4: long (nullable = true)
...
```

What I would like to do is flatten this dataframe so that the `prop_1 ... prop_n` exist at the top level. I.e.

```
test.printSchema
root
|-- prop_1: string (nullable = true)
|-- prop_2: string (nullable = true)
|-- prop_3: boolean (nullable = true)
|-- prop_4: long (nullable = true)
...
```

There are several solutions to similar problems. The best I can find is posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32906927/3112506). However, solution only works if `properties` is of type `Array`. In my case, properties is of type `StructType`.

An alternate approach would be something like:

```
test.registerTempTable("test")
val test2 = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT properties.prop_1, ... FROM test""")
```

But in this case I have to explicitly specify each row, and that is inelegant.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flatten a struct in a Spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753898/how-to-flatten-a-struct-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're not looking for a recursive solution then in 1.6+ dot syntax with star should work just fine:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(Seq(
  """{"properties": {
       "prop1": "foo", "prop2": "bar", "prop3": true, "prop4": 1}}"""
)))

df.select($"properties.*").printSchema
// root
//  |-- prop1: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- prop2: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- prop3: boolean (nullable = true)
//  |-- prop4: long (nullable = true)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work in 1.5 and before.

In case like this you can simply extract required information directly from the schema. You'll find one example in [Dropping a nested column from Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32727279/1560062) which should be easy to adjust to fit this scenario and another one (recursive schema flattening in Python) [Pyspark: Map a SchemaRDD into a SchemaRDD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31521261/1560062).