# How to flatten a struct in a Spark dataframe?

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- keyNote: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- note: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- details: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

How it is possible to flatten the structure and create a new dataframe:

```
     |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- keyNote: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- note: string (nullable = true)
     |-- details: map (nullable = true)
     |    |-- key: string
     |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Is there something like explode, but for structs?

Comment: The answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471346/automatically-and-elegantly-flatten-dataframe-in-spark-sql were also helpful.

Comment: a nice solution is also presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285871/exploded-struct-in-spark?rq=1

Answer (score 133, accepted):

This should work in Spark 1.6 or later:

```
df.select(df.col("data.*"))
```

or

```
df.select(df.col("data.id"), df.col("data.keyNote"), df.col("data.details"))
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field *

Comment: but using select on all the columns like df.select(df.col1, df.col2, df.col3) works, so I will accept this answer

Comment: I was just editing but it is strange. I can use *. Maybe some version issue?

Comment: Yeah maybe. I'm using spark 1.6.1 and scala 2.10

Comment: How would you select key or note under the nested struct keyNote?

Comment: when I am selecting as df.select("data.*'), it gives me n*n rows. (Duplicated n rows for each row).
My data frame having n-2 distinct rows, so if I put distinct it gives me n-2 result. 
But I want n results, which is actually present in my data. How can I achieve this using above mentioned select command.

Comment: Shouldn't it be F.col instead of df.col inside the select?

Answer (score 40):

Here is function that is doing what you want and that can deal with multiple nested columns containing columns with same name:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def flatten_df(nested_df):
    flat_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] != 'struct']
    nested_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] == 'struct']

    flat_df = nested_df.select(flat_cols +
                               [F.col(nc+'.'+c).alias(nc+'_'+c)
                                for nc in nested_cols
                                for c in nested_df.select(nc+'.*').columns])
    return flat_df
```

Before:

```
root
 |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |-- y: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- bar: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
```

After:

```
root
 |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |-- y: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foo_a: float (nullable = true)
 |-- foo_b: float (nullable = true)
 |-- foo_c: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- bar_a: float (nullable = true)
 |-- bar_b: float (nullable = true)
 |-- bar_c: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 19):

For Spark 2.4.5,

while,`df.select(df.col("data.*"))` will give you `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field * in` exception

this will work:-

```
df.select($"data.*")
```

Comment: This works with Spark 3.1.0 too, but it doesn't preserve the `data` or whatever is parent is selected -- and doesn't descend if there are further nested structs.

Comment: when I am selecting as df.select("data.*'), it gives me n*n rows. (Duplicated n rows for each row). My data frame having n-2 distinct rows, so if I put distinct it gives me n-2 result. But I want n results, which is actually present in my data. How can I achieve this using above mentioned select command.

Comment: the dollar can be omitted :)

Comment: Tested with DBR 9.1, Spark 3.1.2 and it works. `df.select("data.*")`

Answer (score 15):

This `flatten_df` version flattens the dataframe at every layer level, using a stack to avoid recursive calls:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col


def flatten_df(nested_df):
    stack = [((), nested_df)]
    columns = []

    while len(stack) > 0:
        parents, df = stack.pop()

        flat_cols = [
            col(".".join(parents + (c[0],))).alias("_".join(parents + (c[0],)))
            for c in df.dtypes
            if c[1][:6] != "struct"
        ]

        nested_cols = [
            c[0]
            for c in df.dtypes
            if c[1][:6] == "struct"
        ]

        columns.extend(flat_cols)

        for nested_col in nested_cols:
            projected_df = df.select(nested_col + ".*")
            stack.append((parents + (nested_col,), projected_df))

    return nested_df.select(columns)
```

Example:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructField, StructType


schema = StructType([
    StructField("some", StringType()),

    StructField("nested", StructType([
        StructField("nestedchild1", StringType()),
        StructField("nestedchild2", StringType())
    ])),

    StructField("renested", StructType([
        StructField("nested", StructType([
            StructField("nestedchild1", StringType()),
            StructField("nestedchild2", StringType())
        ]))
    ]))
])

data = [
    {
        "some": "value1",
        "nested": {
            "nestedchild1": "value2",
            "nestedchild2": "value3",
        },
        "renested": {
            "nested": {
                "nestedchild1": "value4",
                "nestedchild2": "value5",
            }
        }
    }
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
flat_df = flatten_df(df)
print(flat_df.collect())
```

Prints:

```sh
[Row(some=u'value1', renested_nested_nestedchild1=u'value4', renested_nested_nestedchild2=u'value5', nested_nestedchild1=u'value2', nested_nestedchild2=u'value3')]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to recurse into nested structs inside arrays.

Comment: @malthe It won't. I don't think it's feasible to do that, actually. Assuming you use the array index as column name (e.g. array.0.field, array.1.field, ...), you'll have to know the length of the array beforehand. All these solutions iterate the dataframe structure, which is known at the driver.

Comment: I ended up figuring out how to do it and posted a script here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66482320/647151.

Comment: Oh, so the idea was to keep the array but transform the structures it contains. Nice!

Comment: how could you prevent certain columns from getting flattened using this approach?

Comment: If this code is original to this answer then feels like you should have been credited here! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/how-to-analyze-complex-schema#define-a-function-to-flatten-the-nested-schema

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah, I wrote that code snippet just for this answer.

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/113914

Answer (score 8):

A little more compact and efficient implementation:

No need to create list and iterate on them.
You "act" on fields based on their type (if structures or not).

you create a list and iterate on it, if the column is nested (struct) you need to flat it (.*) else you access with dot notation (parent.child) and replace . with _ (parent_child)

```
def flatten_df(nested_df):
    stack = [((), nested_df)]
    columns = []
    while len(stack) > 0:
        parents, df = stack.pop()
        for column_name, column_type in df.dtypes:
            if column_type[:6] == "struct":
                projected_df = df.select(column_name + ".*")
                stack.append((parents + (column_name,), projected_df))
            else:
                columns.append(col(".".join(parents + (column_name,))).alias("_".join(parents + (column_name,))))
    return nested_df.select(columns)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it is more efficient than the other answers as you say it is, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues and they can learn from it.

Comment: worked perfect for me. You would get more like if you add more explanation for sure.

Comment: what is the data type for "parents" @Domenico Di Nicola

Comment: I had problems when the column_name includes 'dot' in it. i know if it is explicit column name i can use back tick to escape it, but above, i could not do it.

Answer (score 5):

I generalized the solution from stecos a bit more so the flattening can be done on more than two struct layers deep:

```
def flatten_df(nested_df, layers):
    flat_cols = []
    nested_cols = []
    flat_df = []

    flat_cols.append([c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] != 'struct'])
    nested_cols.append([c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] == 'struct'])

    flat_df.append(nested_df.select(flat_cols[0] +
                               [col(nc+'.'+c).alias(nc+'_'+c)
                                for nc in nested_cols[0]
                                for c in nested_df.select(nc+'.*').columns])
                  )
    for i in range(1, layers):
        print (flat_cols[i-1])
        flat_cols.append([c[0] for c in flat_df[i-1].dtypes if c[1][:6] != 'struct'])
        nested_cols.append([c[0] for c in flat_df[i-1].dtypes if c[1][:6] == 'struct'])

        flat_df.append(flat_df[i-1].select(flat_cols[i] +
                                [col(nc+'.'+c).alias(nc+'_'+c)
                                    for nc in nested_cols[i]
                                    for c in flat_df[i-1].select(nc+'.*').columns])
        )

    return flat_df[-1]
```

just call with:

```
my_flattened_df = flatten_df(my_df_having_nested_structs, 3)
```

(second parameter is the level of layers to be flattened, in my case it's 3)

Answer (score 4):

PySpark solution to flatten nested df with both **struct** and **array** types with **any level of depth**. This is improved on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56533459/7131019

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

def flatten_structs(nested_df):
    stack = [((), nested_df)]
    columns = []

    while len(stack) > 0:
        
        parents, df = stack.pop()
        
        array_cols = [
            c[0]
            for c in df.dtypes
            if c[1][:5] == "array"
        ]
        
        flat_cols = [
            f.col(".".join(parents + (c[0],))).alias("_".join(parents + (c[0],)))
            for c in df.dtypes
            if c[1][:6] != "struct"
        ]

        nested_cols = [
            c[0]
            for c in df.dtypes
            if c[1][:6] == "struct"
        ]
        
        columns.extend(flat_cols)

        for nested_col in nested_cols:
            projected_df = df.select(nested_col + ".*")
            stack.append((parents + (nested_col,), projected_df))
        
    return nested_df.select(columns)

def flatten_array_struct_df(df):
    
    array_cols = [
            c[0]
            for c in df.dtypes
            if c[1][:5] == "array"
        ]
    
    while len(array_cols) > 0:
        
        for array_col in array_cols:
            
            cols_to_select = [x for x in df.columns if x != array_col ]
            
            df = df.withColumn(array_col, f.explode(f.col(array_col)))
            
        df = flatten_structs(df)
        
        array_cols = [
            c[0]
            for c in df.dtypes
            if c[1][:5] == "array"
        ]
    return df

flat_df = flatten_array_struct_df(df)
```

Comment: This works very well. and i take the 'responsibility' of using it carefully, since flatten `array of struct` can produce duplicate rows as others said.

Comment: Could you explain what each for loop is doing? I'm specifically interested in learning why you defined those specific numbers (:5, :6) in the functions.

Comment: "array" -> 5 chars, "struct"->6 chars

Comment: Ah the length of a string "array" is 5 and "struct" is 6. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach if, you have to covert only struct types.
I would not suggest converting the array, as it could lead to duplicate records.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType


def flatten_schema(schema, prefix=""):
    return_schema = []
    for field in schema.fields:
        if isinstance(field.dataType, StructType):
            if prefix:
                return_schema = return_schema + flatten_schema(field.dataType, "{}.{}".format(prefix, field.name))
            else:
                return_schema = return_schema + flatten_schema(field.dataType, field.name)
        else:
            if prefix:
                field_path = "{}.{}".format(prefix, field.name)
                return_schema.append(col(field_path).alias(field_path.replace(".", "_")))
            else:
                return_schema.append(field.name)
    return return_schema
```

You can use it as

```
new_schema = flatten_schema(df.schema)
df1 = df.select(se)
df1.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/49532496/17250408
here is solution for `struct` and `array` fields with multilevel nesting

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode


def type_cols(df_dtypes, filter_type):
    cols = []
    for col_name, col_type in df_dtypes:
        if col_type.startswith(filter_type):
            cols.append(col_name)
    return cols


def flatten_df(nested_df, sep='_'):
    nested_cols = type_cols(nested_df.dtypes, "struct")
    flatten_cols = [fc for fc, _ in nested_df.dtypes if fc not in nested_cols]
    for nc in nested_cols:
        for cc in nested_df.select(f"{nc}.*").columns:
            if sep is None:
                flatten_cols.append(col(f"{nc}.{cc}").alias(f"{cc}"))
            else:
                flatten_cols.append(col(f"{nc}.{cc}").alias(f"{nc}{sep}{cc}"))
    return nested_df.select(flatten_cols)


def explode_df(nested_df):
    nested_cols = type_cols(nested_df.dtypes, "array")
    exploded_df = nested_df
    for nc in nested_cols:
        exploded_df = exploded_df.withColumn(nc, explode(col(nc)))
    return exploded_df


def flatten_explode_df(nested_df):
    df = nested_df
    struct_cols = type_cols(nested_df.dtypes, "struct")
    array_cols = type_cols(nested_df.dtypes, "array")
    if struct_cols:
        df = flatten_df(df)
        return flatten_explode_df(df)
    if array_cols:
        df = explode_df(df)
        return flatten_explode_df(df)
    return df


df = flatten_explode_df(nested_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use SQL, you could build a SQL query string to alias nested column as flat ones.

- Retrieve data-frame schema (`df.schema()`)
- Transform schema to SQL
  (for (field : `schema().fields()`) ...
- Query:

  ```
  val newDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT " + sqlGenerated + " FROM source")
  ```

Here is [an example in Java](https://gist.github.com/ebuildy/3de0e2855498e5358e4eed1a4f72ea48).

(I prefer SQL way, so you can easily test it on Spark-shell and it's cross-language).

Answer (score 1):

below worked for me in spark sql

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, expr, posexplode, when}

object StackOverFlowQuestion {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val logger = Logger.getLogger("FlattenTest")
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN)

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("FlattenTest")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:\\Temp\\hive")
      .master("local[2]")
      //.enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val stringTest =
      """{
                               "total_count": 123,
                               "page_size": 20,
                               "another_id": "gdbfdbfdbd",
                               "sen": [{
                                "id": 123,
                                "ses_id": 12424343,
                                "columns": {
                                    "blah": "blah",
                                    "count": 1234
                                },
                                "class": {},
                                "class_timestamps": {},
                                "sentence": "spark is good"
                               }]
                            }
                             """
    val result = List(stringTest)
    val githubRdd=spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(result)
    val gitHubDF=spark.read.json(githubRdd)
    gitHubDF.show()
    gitHubDF.printSchema()

    gitHubDF.registerTempTable("JsonTable")

   spark.sql("with cte as" +
      "(" +
      "select explode(sen) as senArray  from JsonTable" +
      "), cte_2 as" +
      "(" +
      "select senArray.ses_id,senArray.ses_id,senArray.columns.* from cte" +
      ")" +
      "select * from cte_2"
    ).show()

    spark.stop()
}

}
```

output:-

```
+----------+---------+--------------------+-----------+
|another_id|page_size|                 sen|total_count|
+----------+---------+--------------------+-----------+
|gdbfdbfdbd|       20|[[[blah, 1234], 1...|        123|
+----------+---------+--------------------+-----------+

root
 |-- another_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- page_size: long (nullable = true)
 |-- sen: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- columns: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- blah: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sentence: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ses_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- total_count: long (nullable = true)

+--------+--------+----+-----+
|  ses_id|  ses_id|blah|count|
+--------+--------+----+-----+
|12424343|12424343|blah| 1234|
+--------+--------+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for scala spark.

```
val totalMainArrayBuffer=collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()
def flatten_df_Struct(dfTemp:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame,dfTotalOuter:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame=
{
//dfTemp.printSchema
val totalStructCols=dfTemp.dtypes.map(x => x.toString.substring(1,x.toString.size-1)).filter(_.split(",",2)(1).contains("Struct")) // in case i the column names come with the word Struct embedded in it
val mainArrayBuffer=collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()
for(totalStructCol <- totalStructCols)
{
val tempArrayBuffer=collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()
tempArrayBuffer+=s"${totalStructCol.split(",")(0)}.*"
//tempArrayBuffer.toSeq.toDF.show(false)
val columnsInside=dfTemp.selectExpr(tempArrayBuffer:_*).columns
for(column <- columnsInside)
mainArrayBuffer+=s"${totalStructCol.split(",")(0)}.${column} as ${totalStructCol.split(",")(0)}_${column}"
//mainArrayBuffer.toSeq.toDF.show(false)
}
//dfTemp.selectExpr(mainArrayBuffer:_*).printSchema
val nonStructCols=dfTemp.selectExpr(mainArrayBuffer:_*).dtypes.map(x => x.toString.substring(1,x.toString.size-1)).filter(!_.split(",",2)(1).contains("Struct")) // in case i the column names come with the word Struct embedded in it
for (nonStructCol <- nonStructCols)
totalMainArrayBuffer+=s"${nonStructCol.split(",")(0).replace("_",".")} as ${nonStructCol.split(",")(0)}" // replacing _ by . in origial select clause if it's an already nested column 
dfTemp.selectExpr(mainArrayBuffer:_*).dtypes.map(x => x.toString.substring(1,x.toString.size-1)).filter(_.split(",",2)(1).contains("Struct")).size 
match {
case value if value ==0 => dfTotalOuter.selectExpr(totalMainArrayBuffer:_*)
case _ => flatten_df_Struct(dfTemp.selectExpr(mainArrayBuffer:_*),dfTotalOuter)
}
}


def flatten_df(dfTemp:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame=
{
var totalArrayBuffer=collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()
val totalNonStructCols=dfTemp.dtypes.map(x => x.toString.substring(1,x.toString.size-1)).filter(!_.split(",",2)(1).contains("Struct")) // in case i the column names come with the word Struct embedded in it
for (totalNonStructCol <- totalNonStructCols)
totalArrayBuffer+=s"${totalNonStructCol.split(",")(0)}"
totalMainArrayBuffer.clear
flatten_df_Struct(dfTemp,dfTemp) // flattened schema is now in totalMainArrayBuffer 
totalArrayBuffer=totalArrayBuffer++totalMainArrayBuffer
dfTemp.selectExpr(totalArrayBuffer:_*)
}


flatten_df(dfTotal.withColumn("tempStruct",lit(5))).printSchema
```

File

```
{"num1":1,"num2":2,"bool1":true,"bool2":false,"double1":4.5,"double2":5.6,"str1":"a","str2":"b","arr1":[3,4,5],"map1":{"cool":1,"okay":2,"normal":3},"carInfo":{"Engine":{"Make":"sa","Power":{"IC":"900","battery":"165"},"Redline":"11500"} ,"Tyres":{"Make":"Pirelli","Compound":"c1","Life":"120"}}}
{"num1":3,"num2":4,"bool1":false,"bool2":false,"double1":4.2,"double2":5.5,"str1":"u","str2":"n","arr1":[6,7,9],"map1":{"fast":1,"medium":2,"agressive":3},"carInfo":{"Engine":{"Make":"na","Power":{"IC":"800","battery":"150"},"Redline":"10000"} ,"Tyres":{"Make":"Pirelli","Compound":"c2","Life":"100"}}}
{"num1":8,"num2":4,"bool1":true,"bool2":true,"double1":5.7,"double2":7.5,"str1":"t","str2":"k","arr1":[11,12,23],"map1":{"preserve":1,"medium":2,"fast":3},"carInfo":{"Engine":{"Make":"ta","Power":{"IC":"950","battery":"170"},"Redline":"12500"} ,"Tyres":{"Make":"Pirelli","Compound":"c3","Life":"80"}}}
{"num1":7,"num2":9,"bool1":false,"bool2":true,"double1":33.2,"double2":7.5,"str1":"b","str2":"u","arr1":[12,14,5],"map1":{"normal":1,"preserve":2,"agressive":3},"carInfo":{"Engine":{"Make":"pa","Power":{"IC":"920","battery":"160"},"Redline":"11800"} ,"Tyres":{"Make":"Pirelli","Compound":"c4","Life":"70"}}}
```

Before:

```
root
 |-- arr1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- bool1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- bool2: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- carInfo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Engine: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Make: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Power: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- IC: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- battery: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Redline: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Tyres: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Compound: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Life: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Make: string (nullable = true)
 |-- double1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- double2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- map1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- agressive: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- cool: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fast: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- medium: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- normal: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- okay: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- preserve: long (nullable = true)
 |-- num1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- num2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- str1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- str2: string (nullable = true
```

After:

```
root
 |-- arr1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- bool1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- bool2: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- double1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- double2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- num1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- num2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- str1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- str2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- map1_agressive: long (nullable = true)
 |-- map1_cool: long (nullable = true)
 |-- map1_fast: long (nullable = true)
 |-- map1_medium: long (nullable = true)
 |-- map1_normal: long (nullable = true)
 |-- map1_okay: long (nullable = true)
 |-- map1_preserve: long (nullable = true)
 |-- carInfo_Engine_Make: string (nullable = true)
 |-- carInfo_Engine_Redline: string (nullable = true)
 |-- carInfo_Tyres_Compound: string (nullable = true)
 |-- carInfo_Tyres_Life: string (nullable = true)
 |-- carInfo_Tyres_Make: string (nullable = true)
 |-- carInfo_Engine_Power_IC: string (nullable = true)
 |-- carInfo_Engine_Power_battery: string (nullable = true)
```

Tried for 2 Levels, it worked

Answer (score 1):

###### It handles struct and array type both , whether you wants your array type as column or you want left it as it is.

```
def new_flatten(df, need_as_column):
stack, col_arr = [], []
stack.append((df.schema.fields, '', df))
while len(stack) > 0:
    arr, curr_name, curr_col = stack.pop()
    if curr_name != '':
        curr_name += '_'
    for x in arr:
        if str(x.dataType).startswith('StructType'):
            stack.append((x.dataType.fields, curr_name+x.name, curr_col[x.name]))
        elif str(x.dataType).startswith('ArrayType'):
            if need_as_column:
                elem_type = str(x.dataType.elementType)
                length = df.select(size(curr_col[x.name]).alias('my_size')).agg(max('my_size')).head()[0]
                for i in range(length):
                    if elem_type.startswith('StructType'):
                        stack.append((x.dataType.elementType.fields, curr_name + x.name + '_' + str(i), curr_col[x.name][i]))
                    else:
                        col_arr.append(curr_col[x.name].getItem(i).alias((curr_name + x.name + '_' + str(i)).lower())) 
            else:
                col_arr.append(curr_col[x.name].alias(curr_name+x.name))
        else:
            col_arr.append(curr_col[x.name].alias(curr_name+x.name))
return df.select(col_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

We used https://github.com/lvhuyen/SparkAid It works to any Level

from sparkaid import flatten

flatten(df_nested_B).printSchema()

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mix of multi-level nested structs and arrays, the code below will help.

The code defines a class called `NestedDF` that can be used to flatten a mix of nested structs and nested arrays in a PySpark dataframe.

**In a hurry?** Here's One-Liner showing how to use the code right-away:

`nested_df = NestedDF(my_df).flattened_df` ...just replace `my_df` with your pyspark data_frame

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col, size
    from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType

    class NestedDF:
    """A class for flattening nested dataframes in PySpark."""

    def __init__(self, nested_df):
        """
        Args:
            nested_df (pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame): Nested dataframe.
        """

        self.nested_df = nested_df
        self.flattened_struct_df = self.flatten_struct_df()
        self.flattened_df = self.flatten_array_df()

    def flatten_array_df(self):
        """Flatten a nested array dataframe into a single level dataframe.

        Returns:
            pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame: Flattened dataframe.

        """
        cols = self.flattened_struct_df.columns
        for col_name in cols:
            if isinstance(self.flattened_struct_df.schema[col_name].dataType, ArrayType):
                array_len = self.flattened_struct_df.select(size(col(col_name)).alias("array_len")).collect()[0]["array_len"]
                for i in range(array_len):
                    self.flattened_struct_df = self.flattened_struct_df.withColumn(col_name + "_" + str(i), self.flattened_struct_df[col_name].getItem(i))
                self.flattened_struct_df = self.flattened_struct_df.drop(col_name)
        return self.flattened_struct_df

    def flatten_struct_df(self):
        """Flatten a nested dataframe into a single level dataframe.
        Returns:
            pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame: Flattened dataframe.
        """
        stack=[((), self.nested_df)]
        columns=[]
        while len(stack)>0:
            parents, df=stack.pop()
            for col_name, col_type in df.dtypes:
                if col_type.startswith('struct'):
                    stack.append((parents+(col_name,), df.select(col_name+".*")))
                else:
                    columns.append(col(".".join(parents+(col_name,))).alias("_".join(parents+(col_name,))))
        return self.nested_df.select(columns)
```

**Explanation:**

The class has two methods: `flatten_array_df()` and `flatten_struct_df()`.

`flatten_array_df()` flattens a nested array dataframe into a single-level dataframe. It first calls the `flatten_struct_df()` method to convert any nested structs in the dataframe into a single-level dataframe. Then, it iterates over the columns of the resulting dataframe and checks if each column contains an array. If a column contains an array, it calculates the length of the array and then iterates over each element of the array. For each element, it creates a new column in the dataframe with a name that combines the original column name and the index of the element. Finally, it drops the original column and returns the resulting flattened dataframe.

`flatten_struct_df()` flattens a nested dataframe that contains structs into a single-level dataframe. It first creates an empty stack and adds a tuple containing an empty tuple and the input nested dataframe to the stack. It then iteratively pops the top tuple from the stack and checks if each column of the corresponding dataframe contains a struct. If a column contains a struct, it adds a new tuple to the stack that contains the original column name as well as the struct's columns, and selects only those columns from the original dataframe. If a column does not contain a struct, it constructs a new column name by combining the column names of all of its parent structs and the original column name, and adds the resulting column to a list. Finally, it selects the columns in the list and returns the resulting flattened dataframe.