# How to convert this nested json in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

df.printSchema()

```
root
|-- country: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- d: string (nullable = true)

Row(trustset=Row(a=1, b='Melbourne is in Aus', c=None, d='Sydney'))
```

df.show()

```
+--------------------+
|            trustset|
+--------------------+
|[1, Melbourne is ...|
+--------------------+
```

My desired output must be

```
+------+------------------------+-----+--------+
|   a  |    b                   |  c  |   d    |
+------+------------------------+-----+--------+
|   1  |  Melbourne is in Aus   | None| Sydney |
+------+------------------------+-----+--------+
```

have been getting trustset as the column need to the subs as main columns

Comment: df.select(df.col("trustset.*")) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753898/how-to-flatten-a-struct-in-a-spark-dataframe

Comment: Used this  `df.select(df.columns("trustset.*"))` got `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`    used this `df.select(df.col("trustset.*"))` got  `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'`

Comment: There is no such thing as a nested JSON. [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. And there is no JSON in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrame's select can help you select nested fields in struct

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df.select(col("trustset.*")).show()
```

There's a similar question: [How to flatten a struct in a Spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753898/how-to-flatten-a-struct-in-a-spark-dataframe)