# Using flatMap / reduce: dealing with rows containing a list of rows

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, mapreduce, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe containing an array of rows on each row

I want to aggregate all the inner rows into one dataframe

Below is what I have / achieved:

This

```
df.select('*').take(1)
```

Gives me this:

```
[
   Row(
       body=[
               Row(a=1, b=1), 
               Row(a=2, b=2)
            ]
      )
]
```

So doing this:

```
df.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

I get this:

```
[[
   Row(a=1, b=1)
   Row(a=2, b=2)
]]
```

So I am forced to do this:

```
df.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).flatMap(lambda x: x)
```

So I can achieve the below:

```
[
  Row(a=1, b=1) 
  Row(a=2, b=2)
]
```

Using the result above, I can finally convert it to a dataframe and save somewhere.  Which is what I want. But calling flatMap twice doesnt look right.

I tried to the same by using Reduce, just like the following code:

```
flatRdd = df.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)        
dfMerged = reduce(DataFrame.unionByName, [flatRdd])
```

The second argument of reduce must be iterable, so I was forced to add [flatRdd]. Sadly it gives me this:

```
[[
   Row(a=1, b=1)
   Row(a=2, b=2)
]]
```

There is certainlly a better way to achieve what I want.

Comment: Does `body` always have the same number of elements? What version of spark?

Comment: I am using Apache Spark 2.4.3, Python 3. The number of elements and columns will  not be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can `explode` and then flatten the resulting `Row`s using the `.*` syntax.

Suppose you start with the following DataFrame:

```python
df.show()
#+----------------+
#|            body|
#+----------------+
#|[[1, 1], [2, 2]]|
#+----------------+
```

with the schema:

```python
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- body: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
```

You can first `explode` the `body` column:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df = df.select(explode("body").alias("exploded"))
df.show()
#+--------+
#|exploded|
#+--------+
#|  [1, 1]|
#|  [2, 2]|
#+--------+
```

Now [flatten the `exploded` column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753898/how-to-flatten-a-struct-in-a-spark-dataframe/49532496):

```python
df = df.select("exploded.*")
df.show()
#+---+---+
#|  a|  b|
#+---+---+
#|  1|  1|
#|  2|  2|
#+---+---+
```

Now if you were to call `collect`, you'd get the desired output:

```python
print(df.collect())
#[Row(a=1, b=1), Row(a=2, b=2)]
```

See also:

- [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332494/querying-spark-sql-dataframe-with-complex-types)

Comment: Thanks man! This is actually very good, explod returned a typed dataframe to me, based on the rows I haave inside the body. With flatMap, I had to use toDF(schema).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run flatMap() on the Row object, just refer it directly with the key:

```
>>> df.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.body).collect()
[Row(a=1, b=1), Row(a=2, b=2)]
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked, but I set the the answer to @pault because, his way worked better for my case