# How to sort columns of nested structs alphabetically in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, struct, pyspark

I have data with below schema. I want all the columns should be in sorted alphabetically. I want it in pyspark data frame.

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pin: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
```

The below code sorts only the outer columns but not the nested columns.

```
>>> cols = df.columns
>>> df2=df[sorted(cols)]
>>> df2.printSchema()
```

The schema after this code looks like

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pin: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
```

(since there's underscore at id, it appears first)

The schema which I want is as below. (Even the columns inside the address should be sorted)

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pin: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a sample data to check with?

Comment: @samkart we need only column names here. we're not gonna do anything with the data right, so I don't think it needs sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that should work for arbitrarily deeply nested `StructType`s which doesn't rely on hard coding any column names.

To demonstrate, I've created the following slightly more complex schema, where there is a second level of nesting within the `address` column. Let's suppose that your DataFrame `schema` were the following:

```
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
# |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- pin: integer (nullable = true)
# |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- zip: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- last4: integer (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- first5: integer (nullable = true)
# |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
```

Notice the `address.zip` field which contains 2 out of order sub fields.

You can define a function that will recursively step through your `schema` and sort the fields to build a Spark-SQL select expression:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField

def schemaToSelectExpr(schema, baseField=""):
    select_cols = []
    for structField in sorted(schema, key=lambda x: x.name):
        if structField.dataType.typeName() == 'struct':

            subFields = []
            for fld in sorted(structField.jsonValue()['type']['fields'], 
                              key=lambda x: x['name']):
                newStruct = StructType([StructField.fromJson(fld)])
                newBaseField = structField.name
                if baseField:
                    newBaseField = baseField + "." + newBaseField
                subFields.extend(schemaToSelectExpr(newStruct, baseField=newBaseField))

            select_cols.append(
                "struct(" + ",".join(subFields) + ") AS {}".format(structField.name)
            )
        else:
            if baseField:
                select_cols.append(baseField + "." + structField.name)
            else:
                select_cols.append(structField.name)
    return select_cols
```

Running this on this DataFrame's schema yields (I've broken the long 'address' string into two lines for readability):

```
print(schemaToSelectExpr(df.schema))
#['_id',
#'struct(address.city,address.pin,address.street,
#        struct(address.zip.first5,address.zip.last4) AS zip) AS address',
# 'first_name',
# 'last_name']
```

Now use `selectExpr` to sort the columns:

```
df = df.selectExpr(schemaToSelectExpr(df.schema))
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
# |-- address: struct (nullable = false)
# |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- pin: integer (nullable = true)
# |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- zip: struct (nullable = false)
# |    |    |-- first5: integer (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- last4: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: This seems to change the `nullable` property of the `struct`s - I will see if I can fix that.

Comment: Note that this does not work for structs which are nested in arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You can first flatten your DF with the nice `colname.*` synthax for struct types. For nested flattening you can use this: [How to flatten a struct in a Spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753898/how-to-flatten-a-struct-in-a-spark-dataframe/49532496).

On the flattened dataframe you can then create a new StructCol with input cols sorted:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
address_cols = df.select(F.col("address.*")).columns
df = df.withColumn(address, F.struct(*sorted([F.col(c) for c in address_cols])))
df2 = df[sorted(df.columns)]
```

Comment: This is a good start, but the code you have breaks for a number of reasons.

Comment: Throwing error at this line 

df = df.withColumn(address, F.struct(*sorted([F.col(c) for c in address_cols])))

even quotation marks for address is not working