# PySpark: Flatten Struct

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there a way to flatten a `struct` object in PySpark?

```
root
 |-- key: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

I found this SO post: [How to flatten a struct in a Spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753898/how-to-flatten-a-struct-in-a-spark-dataframe) to be similar, except I didn't know how to translate the answer(s) from Spark to PySpark.

**SOLUTION**: For others, here is the full code solution that I was looking for:

```
df.select(col("key.id"), 
          col("key.type"),
          col("key.date"))
```

Comment: The link you mentioned is useful for this. Read the article completely, Let me know if still needed help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is same for spark in Scala, Java and Python. To access fields of struct you need to use dot(.) operator like below.

```
df.select(col("key.id"))
```

The above line of code will fetch only id.