# how can i flatten a schema

Tags: struct, schema, databricks

I have a schema like this

```
root
 |-- CaseNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Interactions: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- EmailInteractions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- PhoneInteractions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CreatedOn: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Direction: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- WebInteractions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

How can I make it like this

```
root
 |-- CaseNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreatedOn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Direction: string (nullable = true)
```

Any help would be apperciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flatten a struct in a Spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753898/how-to-flatten-a-struct-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Comment: I tried like this using the link 

val dl4=dl3.select($"CaseNumber",dl3.col("Interactions.*"))

but it raises this error " No such struct field * in EmailInteractions, PhoneInteractions, WebInteractions;" which I think it is because I have arrays inside

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dl4=dl3.select([$"CaseNumber",$"Interactions.PhoneInteractions.CreatedOn",$"Interactions.PhoneInteractions.Direction"])
```

Comment: Yes, this one works good, thanks. a quick q her..as you see from the above schema the "Email Interaction" is an array but when I could not explode it, I believe "created On" and "Direction" column are also there, is there any way I could know if those columns also exist under Email interactions?

Comment: Try this: `var explodedDf3 = dl3.select("EmailInteractions.*","*")` or add those columns back in like this: `val explodeDF2 = explodeDF.withColumn("id", explodeDF("department.id")).withColumn("name", explodeDF2("department.name"))`

Comment: Thanks @Goldengenova.. I see where the issue is coming from. I have daily files that I read and now I am aware that in each daily file the schema changes on those three arrays("Email,Phone,Web interactions) for example in today's file I saw that Email interactions array does not have a structure like above where as phone interactions has the same structure which email int had on top of one. Do you know how can ignore errors in notebook databricks when exploding if it did not find the right structure?