# Flatten nested array in Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm reading in some JSON on the from:

```json
{"a": [{"b": {"c": 1, "d": 2}}]}
```

That is, the array items are unnecessarily nested. Now, because this happens inside an array, the answers given in [How to flatten a struct in a Spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753898/how-to-flatten-a-struct-in-a-spark-dataframe/65256608) don't apply directly.

This is how the dataframe looks when parsed:

```
root
|-- a: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- b: struct
|    |    |    |-- c: integer
|    |    |    |-- d: integer
```

I'm looking to transform the dataframe into this:

```
root
|-- a: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- b_c: integer
|    |    |-- b_d: integer
```

How do I go about aliasing the columns inside the array to effectively unnest it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `transform`:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr("transform(a, x -> struct(x.b.c as b_c, x.b.d as b_d)) as a")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the method presented in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66476985/647151) I wrote a function to recursively unnest a dataframe (recursing into nested arrays as well):

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructType

def flatten(df, sentinel="x"):
    def _gen_flatten_expr(schema, indent, parents, last, transform=False):
        def handle(field, last):
            path = parents + (field.name,)
            alias = (
                " as "
                + "_".join(path[1:] if transform else path)
                + ("," if not last else "")
            )
            if isinstance(field.dataType, StructType):
                yield from _gen_flatten_expr(
                    field.dataType, indent, path, last, transform
                )
            elif (
                isinstance(field.dataType, ArrayType) and
                isinstance(field.dataType.elementType, StructType)
            ):
                yield indent, "transform("
                yield indent + 1, ".".join(path) + ","
                yield indent + 1, sentinel + " -> struct("
                yield from _gen_flatten_expr(
                    field.dataType.elementType, 
                    indent + 2, 
                    (sentinel,), 
                    True, 
                    True
                )
                yield indent + 1, ")"
                yield indent, ")" + alias
            else:
                yield (indent, ".".join(path) + alias)

        try:
            *fields, last_field = schema.fields
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            for field in fields:
                yield from handle(field, False)
            yield from handle(last_field, last)

    lines = []
    for indent, line in _gen_flatten_expr(df.schema, 0, (), True):
        spaces = " " * 4 * indent
        lines.append(spaces + line)

    expr = "struct(" + "\n".join(lines) + ") as " + sentinel
    return df.selectExpr(expr).select(sentinel + ".*")
```

Comment: this does absolutely nothing for me

Comment: @Garglesoap can you reduce your problem to a short example that can be shared here?

Comment: Sorry I was fustrated. I found something like this to work: newdf = result.withColumn("sentiment", explode("sentiment")).select("*",col("sentiment.*")).drop("document","sentence","tokens","word_embeddings","sentence_embeddings","sentiment")

Answer (score 1):

Simplified Approach:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def flatten_df(nested_df):
    stack = [((), nested_df)]
    columns = []

    while len(stack) > 0:
        parents, df = stack.pop()

        flat_cols = [
            col(".".join(parents + (c[0],))).alias("_".join(parents + (c[0],)))
            for c in df.dtypes
            if c[1][:6] != "struct"
        ]

        nested_cols = [
            c[0]
            for c in df.dtypes
            if c[1][:6] == "struct"
        ]

        columns.extend(flat_cols)

        for nested_col in nested_cols:
            projected_df = df.select(nested_col + ".*")
            stack.append((parents + (nested_col,), projected_df))

    return nested_df.select(columns)
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/how-to-analyze-complex-schema