# Flatten a nested json document using spark and load into Elasticsearch

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I am relatively new to Spark and java programming. Given a json file with nested objects I need to flatten its structure(denorm the contents) and load into Elastisearch using spark.

For instance,

if the contents of my example.json is:

```
{
  "title": "Nest eggs",
  "body":  "Making your money work...",
  "tags":  [ "cash", "shares" ],
  "comments": 
    {
      "name":    "John Smith",
      "comment": "Great article",
      "age":     28,
      "stars":   4,
      "date":    "2014-09-01"
    }
  "owner": 
    {
      "name":    "John Smith",
      "age":     28,
    }
}
```

I would want to reconstruct this in the below format and load it into ES using spark.

```
{
  "title": "Nest eggs",
  "body":  "Making your money work...",
  "tags":  [ "cash", "shares" ],
  "comments_name": "John Smith",
  "comments_comment": "Great article",
  "comments_age":     28
  "comments_stars":   4,
  "comments_date":    "2014-09-01"
  "owner_name": "John Smith",
  "owner_age":     28,
 }
```

In case one of the nested objects is empty, the contents can be left empty too.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Semantically, there's no difference between `"comments.name"` (a field `name` nested instead a `comments` field) and `"comments_name"` (a top-level field)

Comment: Agreed. It can be in either form. I want it to be a flattened json before loading it to the index in ES.

Answer (score -1):

The answer you are looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027966/elegant-json-flatten-in-spark).

To summarize, you can just select out the fields you need via dot notation.

```
val df = sqlcontext.read.json(json)    
val flattened = df.select($"title", $"comments.name")
```

Comment: I think he asked for an automatic solution