# How to convert spark streaming nested json coming on kafka to flat dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

need some help on my first attempt to parse JSON coming on Kafka to Spark structured streaming.

I am struggling to convert the incoming JSON and covert it into flat dataframe for further processing.

My input json is

```
[
    { "siteId": "30:47:47:BE:16:8F", "siteData": 
        [
            { "dataseries": "trend-255", "values": 
                [
                    {"ts": 1502715600, "value": 35.74 },
                    {"ts": 1502715660, "value": 35.65 },
                    {"ts": 1502715720, "value": 35.58 },
                    {"ts": 1502715780, "value": 35.55 }
                ]
            },
            { "dataseries": "trend-256", "values":
                [
                    {"ts": 1502715840, "value": 18.45 },
                    {"ts": 1502715900, "value": 18.35 },
                    {"ts": 1502715960, "value": 18.32 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    { "siteId": "30:47:47:BE:16:FF", "siteData": 
        [
            { "dataseries": "trend-255", "values": 
                [
                    {"ts": 1502715600, "value": 35.74 },
                    {"ts": 1502715660, "value": 35.65 },
                    {"ts": 1502715720, "value": 35.58 },
                    {"ts": 1502715780, "value": 35.55 }
                ]
            },
            { "dataseries": "trend-256", "values":
                [
                    {"ts": 1502715840, "value": 18.45 },
                    {"ts": 1502715900, "value": 18.35 },
                    {"ts": 1502715960, "value": 18.32 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Spark schema is

```py
data1_spark_schema = ArrayType(
StructType([
  StructField("siteId", StringType(), False),
  StructField("siteData", ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("dataseries", StringType(), False),
    StructField("values", ArrayType(StructType([
      StructField("ts", IntegerType(), False),
      StructField("value", StringType(), False)
    ]), False), False)
  ]), False), False)
]), False
)
```

My very simple code is:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

from config.general import kafka_instance
from config.general import topic
from schemas.schema import data1_spark_schema

spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .appName("Structured_BMS_Feed") \
            .getOrCreate()

stream = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_instance) \
        .option("subscribe", topic) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
        .option("max.poll.records", 100) \
        .option("failOnDataLoss", False) \
        .load()

stream_records = stream.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING) as bms_data1") \
                       .select(from_json("bms_data1", data1_spark_schema).alias("bms_data1"))

sites = stream_records.select(explode("bms_data1").alias("site")) \
                      .select("site.*")

sites.printSchema()

stream_debug = sites.writeStream \
                             .outputMode("append") \
                             .format("console") \
                             .option("numRows", 20) \
                             .option("truncate", False) \
                             .start()


stream_debug.awaitTermination()
```

When I run this code I schema is printing like this:

```
root
 |-- siteId: string (nullable = false)
 |-- siteData: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- dataseries: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- values: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ts: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = false)
```

Is it possible to have this schema in a way where I get all fields in a flat dataframe instead of nested JSON. So for every ts and value it should give me one row with its parent dataseries and site id.

Comment: Seems duplicate question: [refer this]: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027966/elegant-json-flatten-in-spark)

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. I managed to flatten it using following lines:

```
sites_flat = stream_records.select(explode("bms_data1").alias("site")) \
                           .select("site.siteId", explode("site.siteData").alias("siteData")) \
                           .select("siteId", "siteData.dataseries", explode("siteData.values").alias("values")) \
                           .select("siteId", "dataseries", "values.*")
```